# Facebook Sandbox Browser

Tags: firefox, security, privacy, facebook

How can I make firefox operate as a [site-specific](https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/a-single-site-browsers-impact-on-xss-csrf-and-clickjacking.318114/) browser?

The goal is security through compartmentalization. Specifically, to thwart facebook's attempts to track & store all of my internet browsing activity, including when I'm [not on the facebook website](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/alexkantrowitz/heres-how-facebook-tracks-you-when-youre-not-on-facebook).

Ideally, I'd like to have one browser operate such that it can *only* access facebook and my other browser operate such that it can access every site *except* facebook's.

Please let me know how I can setup firefox to operate as a Facebook-Specific (Single-Site) browser.

Comment: You may use two profiles. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiple_profiles

Comment: Using private mode will also minimize what's available to Facebook.

Comment: profiles don't solve the issue as facebook can still track you when you're not on facebook, as described in the buzzfeed article linked-to in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

[Facebook Container](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-container/). This add-on isolates Facebook in your browser. This is probably all you need.

If you want to be more certain, use two [Profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data). Install some website blocking plugins in both of them. Blacklist Facebook in first profile, whitelist only Facebook in second.

Comment: great answer! what "website blocking plugins" do you recommend for blacklisting & whitelisting in Firefox?

Comment: so I understand that this plugin makes it so that typing 'facebook.com' into a new tab automatically makes that tab use a facebook-specific container. That's a great start.

But what about requests made to facebook.com when I'm browsing someblog.net that has a facebook like button? Do those requests get blocked entirely? Or is there some sub-tab segmentation that makes the requests to someblog.net come from a distinct container than facebook.com's requests?

Comment: And what about requests made to the other [facebook domains](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/additional-configuration/domains/)? ie: facebook.com, fbcdn.net, fb.me, fbsbx.com, and workplace.com

And what about requests made to Facebook-owned ip addresses? Does Facebook Container block by domain names only? Or IP addresses as well?

Comment: I don't think I can answer all of your questions :) I don't know how Facebook Container deals with embedded buttons, it probably loads them but they use a separate, non-containerized cookie set. You can block them with Privacy Badget or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `firejail` in linux, where you can use the `--netfilter` argument to:

[a] define iptables rules to block access to all of the ip netblocks owned by Facebook in your *Main Browser* and

[b] define iptables rules to block access to the entire Internet *except* those ip netblocks owned by Facebook in a *Facebook-Specific* (sandbox) browser

A list of ip netblocks owned by Facebook can be found using a whois Autonomous System (AS) number for Facebook, Inc = AS32934

```
root@disp355:/home/user# whois -h whois.radb.net -- \
root@disp355:/home/user# '-i origin AS32934'| grep -e "^route:"
...
route:      69.63.176.0/20
route:      66.220.144.0/20
route:      66.220.144.0/21
route:      69.63.184.0/21
route:      69.63.176.0/21
route:      74.119.76.0/22
route:      69.171.255.0/24
route:      173.252.64.0/18
route:      69.171.224.0/19
route:      69.171.224.0/20
root@disp355:/home/user#
```

The entire list can then be put into a netfilter file for your Facebook-Specific browser:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/firejail/facebookOnly.net
################################################################################
# Author:  Michael Altfield <michael@michaelaltfield.net>
# Created: 2019-03-25
# Updated: 2019-03-25
# Version: 0.1
# Purpose: Permits traffic to/from facebook (and dns) only
################################################################################
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]

-A OUTPUT --destination 102.132.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 102.132.96.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 103.4.96.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 129.134.0.0/17 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.0.0/17 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.11.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.12.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.13.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.14.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.15.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.18.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.19.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.193.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.194.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.195.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.20.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.21.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.22.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.24.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.25.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.26.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.27.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.28.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.29.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.30.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.3.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.6.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.7.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.9.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 173.252.64.0/19 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 173.252.88.0/21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 173.252.96.0/19 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.192.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.192.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.193.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.194.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.195.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.216.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.216.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.217.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.218.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.219.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 204.15.20.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.24.0/21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.64.0/19 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.64.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.65.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.66.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.67.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.68.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.70.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.71.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.72.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.73.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.74.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.75.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.80.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.81.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.82.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.83.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.84.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.85.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.86.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.87.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.89.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.90.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.91.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.92.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.93.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.94.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.95.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.96.0/19 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 45.64.40.0/22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 66.220.144.0/20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 66.220.144.0/21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 66.220.152.0/21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.224.0/19 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.224.0/20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.239.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.250.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.255.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.63.176.0/20 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.63.176.0/21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.63.184.0/21 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 74.119.76.0/22 -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j DROP

-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP

COMMIT
EOF'
```

Similarly, create the inverse for your main browser:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/firejail/notFacebook.net
################################################################################
# Author:  Michael Altfield <michael@michaelaltfield.net>
# Created: 2019-03-25
# Updated: 2019-03-25
# Version: 0.1
# Purpose: Permits traffic to/from everything except facebook
################################################################################
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A OUTPUT --destination 102.132.96.0/20 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 102.132.96.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 103.4.96.0/22 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 129.134.0.0/17 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.0.0/17 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.10.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.1.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.11.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.12.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.13.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.14.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.15.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.18.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.19.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.192.0/18 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.193.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.194.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.195.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.20.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.2.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.21.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.22.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.24.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.25.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.26.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.27.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.28.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.29.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.30.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.3.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.6.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.7.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.8.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 157.240.9.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 173.252.64.0/19 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 173.252.88.0/21 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 173.252.96.0/19 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.192.0/22 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.192.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.193.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.194.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 179.60.195.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.216.0/22 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.216.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.217.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.218.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 185.60.219.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 204.15.20.0/22 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.24.0/21 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.64.0/18 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.64.0/19 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.64.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.65.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.66.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.67.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.68.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.70.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.71.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.72.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.73.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.74.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.75.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.80.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.81.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.82.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.83.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.84.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.85.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.86.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.87.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.89.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.90.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.91.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.92.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.93.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.94.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.95.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 31.13.96.0/19 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 45.64.40.0/22 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 66.220.144.0/20 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 66.220.144.0/21 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 66.220.152.0/21 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.224.0/19 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.224.0/20 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.239.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.240.0/20 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.250.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.171.255.0/24 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.63.176.0/20 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.63.176.0/21 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 69.63.184.0/21 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT --destination 74.119.76.0/22 -j DROP

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP

COMMIT
EOF'
```

Now you can launch your Facebook-Specific browser using the first netfitler ruleset as follows:

```
firejail --dns="1.1.1.1" --dns="9.9.9.9" --dns="8.8.8.8" --net=eth0 --netfilter=/etc/firejail/facebookOnly.net firefox -no-remote -new-instance "https://www.facebook.com"
```

And for the general-purpose browser that can't "call home" to facebook's servers from the rest of the web:

```
firejail --dns="1.1.1.1" --dns="9.9.9.9" --dns="8.8.8.8" --net=eth0 --netfilter=/etc/firejail/notFacebok.net firefox -no-remote -new-instance "https://start.duckduckgo.com"
```

For more information about this, see the following article:

- https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2019/03/26/ephemeral-firefox-as-a-site-specific-browser-03/